# Problems with react card flip animation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, flip

I'm trying to implement a little pizazz to my React cards grid and I'm running into implementation problems. The approach seems straightforward which is:

1. Import ReactCardFlip from library
2. Declare function that says the card "isFlipped" and sets it as a default
3. Bind a handleClick function to some button that performs the flip after it's pressed.
4. The react card flip library I'm trying to implement is here:
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-card-flip

Here's the code:

```
import cardstyles from "./Card.module.css";
import React, { useState } from "React";
import ReactCardFlip from "react-card-flip";

const cardFlip = () => {
  const [isFlipped, setIsFlipped] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsFlipped(!isFlipped);
  };
};

const Card = (props) => (
  <ReactCardFlip isFlipped={isFlipped} flipDirection="horizontal">
    <div className={cardstyles.card}>
      <div className={cardstyles.front}>
        <img
          src="/crypto_new.jpg"
          alt="crypto small hero"
          className={cardstyles.cardImage}
        />
        <div className={cardstyles.container}>
          <h3>
            New hodl price <span className={cardstyles.price}>$99.99</span>
          </h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc
            suscipit ut dolor non ultrices.
            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                position: "absolute",
                height: "40px",
                width: "auto",
              }}
            >
              <button
                onClick={handleClick}
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  position: "relative",
                  height: "40px",
                  width: "210px",
                  outline: "solid 1px black",
                  fontSize: "18px",
                  borderRadius: "2px",
                  textShadow: "0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.42)",
                }}
              >
                {" "}
                Buy Now{" "}
              </button>
            </div>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ReactCardFlip>
);

export default Card;
```

What am I missing?

THANKS

PS--If you want to run on your local machine then here is the repo below:
https://github.com/freeSc0tt/react-cardsII
PPS-- I am getting this error here "ReferenceError: isFlipped is not defined"

Comment: isFlipped is indeed not defined within Card component. It's just defined in cardFlip function.

Comment: Try removing the useState where you declare it in card flip and place it within Card

Answer (score 0):

Well my English isn't the best but I will try. I didn't see your back component. You must define it like this:

```
<ReactCardFlip isFlipped={this.state.isFlipped} flipDirection="vertical">
        <div>// YOUR_FRONT_COMPONENT
          This is the front of the card.
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click to flip</button>
        </div>

        <div>// YOUR_BACK_COMPONENT
          This is the back of the card.
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click to flip</button>
        </div>
</ReactCardFlip>
```

I hope that my answer will help you.